# How to package closed-source softwares

Tags: application-development, packaging, proprietary

How to package close source application (proprietary). I know how to package open-source apps using dh_make and pbuilder but using this method others can see my source code. Is there any way for doing this without posiblitiy of exposing source code. 
I can't just send archive to Ubuntu Software Center because they don't know where to put each file.

So can you help me with this.

Comment: Which pgming language is used for your program?

Comment: I'm using Qt C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a *binary* package results in a `.deb` file. This usually does not contain source code, as build artefacts are *binary*.

Exceptions to this is software written in Python, PHP, and other interpreted languages. Because it's interpreted, you can't build without restricting the end users to change the environment (e.g. Python version). And yes, there are workarounds for this, but this is not recommended. The Debian policy for Python for example is to compile it at installation time ([Debian wiki: Python/Policy](http://wiki.debian.org/Python/Policy)).

Feel free to inspect the contents of your package after building. Also see examples of open source software binary packages.

**Edit - Using PPAs:**

When uploading a package to your PPA, it will be a source package and built by Launchpad cloud servers to a binary package. Both will be published. There's no way build your packages locally and publish your binary-only packages to a PPA. You'll have to set up a repository yourself.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this because I'm still begginer at packaging and I was only using PPA so I thought that source code goes in DEB package as well. Thank you.

Comment: A PPA is a kinda different story though. Any package in a PPA is built in Launchpad's cloud, so only source packages are accepted. Then both source and binary packages are published. I'll update my answer accordingly.